# android, app paint how to fill

Tags: java, android

I want to use fill method on a shapes like a circle.

It's working on one side but when I try to fill left and right the app stops 
working.

I don't know what I am  doing wrong; maybe there is easy way.

Here is the fill/draw func (this is not the full paint code) code:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(z==true) {
        int a = (int) (x);
        int b = (int) (y);
        float x1,y1;
        if(canvasBitmap.getPixel(a,b)!=Color.RED)
        {
            for(;a<wo;a++)
            for(;b<ho;b++)
            if(canvasBitmap.getPixel(a,b)!=Color.RED && a<wo)
            {
                x1=(float) (a);
                y1=(float) (b);
                drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, drawPaint);
                canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            }
            else
            {
            a=wo+34;
            b=ho+34;
            }

        }
        else
        {

            drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, drawPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(drawPath,drawPaint);

        }

    }
    else
    switch (pick) {

        case 1:
            drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, drawPaint);
            drawCanvas.drawCircle(x,y,brushSize,drawPaint);
            break;
        case 2:
            drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, drawPaint);
            drawCanvas.drawLine(x, y, brushSize, brushSize, drawPaint);
            break;
        case 3:
            drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, drawPaint);
            drawCanvas.drawRect(x,brushSize,y,brushSize,drawPaint);
            break;
        default:
            drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, drawPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(drawPath,drawPaint);




    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to fill a circle :

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, mOverlayPaint);
}
```

with

```
mOverlayPaint = new Paint();
mOverlayPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
mOverlayPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
```

This simple call in `onDraw` will draw a red circle, you can calculate / decide of your circle position and radius as you wish